# Scraper to use for app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've used Selenium, nokogiri, and mechanize.

I am trying to make my own assumptions for which scraping gem I like the most.  Besides those three what other scraping gems are out there that I should take a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urllib with beautifulsoup is a powerful combination if you're looking to expand beyond ruby and into Python.

Having said that, Selenium is ridiculously good. You may not really need much beyond that and it makes your question moot.